# Chez Scheme 用ライブラリのインストール先

Tags: scheme

[Chez Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) 用にライブラリを導入するときにそれをどこにインストールするかについて、一般的な運用方法はありますか？ または自分なりにこう決めているという事例があれば知りたいです。

どこでも適当なところに入れて環境変数 [`CHEZSCHEMELIBDIRS`](http://scheme.com/csug8/use.html#./use:s42) を設定すればよい話ではあるのですが、自分が作ったライブラリを公開するにあたってインストールスクリプトを用意しようと思っているので、一般的な作法があるならそれに倣いたいと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

残念ながら現状ではデファクトな作法は特にないと思います。GitHub上にあるChez用のライブラリのリポジトリのいくつかでは`Makefile`を提供してはいますが、どのライブラリも最終的に`CHEZSCHEMELIBDIR`を設定することを要求しています。

インストール用のスクリプトをChezで書くのであれば、`library-directories`で得られるalistを使ってインストール先を決めるようにすれば`--libdirs`を指定した`alias`なども解決できるので利便性が高いのではないかと思います。
参照先：[Section 10.5. Library Parameters](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.4/libraries.html#./libraries:h5)